# Why is a Malicious script being added to my web pages and how can i remove it?

Tags: javascript, security, malware

I am a web developer, I've noticed that some random scripts appearing on web pages run on one of my VPS.  the code is also inserting an image into my web pages.

the source of the script is tongjii.us

the image that is being inserted is referencing a website called 'weimaipai.com'

Does any one know what i can do to remove this?

Comment: There is no particular answer, but the generic answer would be: just don't write/deploy vulnerable code.

Comment: A.k.a. stop using wordpress and you should be fine

Comment: @PeeHaa, some say that 1/4 of all sites in the world use wp... How to stop that plague? :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you've provided.. we can't tell you.

There could be so many ways in which this is done, from someone who knows your login details and just uploaded it, to a brute-force attack to guess your password (is it an easy one?) if they did it via logging in.

More likely though is you've either called a remote script that was infected, or you've not ensured form data is properly sanitized. For instance, if you have a comment form which displays on the page it's sometimes possible to insert a comment in javascript which can do all kinds of harm (like calling another script to harvest user information etc.).

Try to make sure all the scripts you are calling remotely are trusted, all your user input is ensured to not be malicious content, your passwords are complex, and you have no virus/keylogger on your computer. If you remove the script and it comes back you may need to contact your hosting company.

Comment: Thank you, you were very helpful. It appears the that someone has entered the malicious code into random javascript files across the VPS, mostly likely  brute-force attack because the password was not very strong.  I have been able to isolate the code and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I can relate as the exact same thing happened on a website on one of my VPS.

The website was not on wordpress..our problem was with a outdated CKEditor.

As stated he issue was traced to a vulnerability in CKEditor where it was possible to upload anything through its media upload function! We addressed the editors vulnerability and then removed all infected scripts.

Hope this helps.